# HTML,CSS using background image

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure this out for awhile now. Trying to use css to add a background image. I'm also using bootstrap. Here is my code

css:

```
.container-fluid{
background-image: url('../DomPic/photo1.jpg');
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid"></div>
```

**Problem:**
The image wont show up on my page.

Comment: please enter full code?

Comment: Thats my full code. the image wont show up on my page

Comment: C:\Users\muna\Desktop\DomWebsite\DomPic thats my path. But I'm pretty sure I inputted the right path.

Comment: background-image: url('DomPic/photo1.jpg');

Comment: Add any text or something in the div.

Comment: @yjs okay that worked. Thanks. Now it seems the image is to zoomed out.

Comment: @CodePanda code modified below;

Answer (score 1):

It is because your div have nothing.

```
<div class="container-fluid">Something</div>
```

Either add something in div.

**Or**

Give fixed width and height. Or at least fixed `height` works.

```
.container-fluid{
background-image: url('../DomPic/photo1.jpg');
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: he didn't explain his problem in detail and neither he provided the details

Comment: It is said in the stackoverflow that "Provide details. Share your research." Providing details in comments is not a good idea

Comment: He should have edited the question to provide more details..so others reading the question can understand his problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
.container-fluid{
position:absolute;
background-image: url('DomPic/photo1.jpg');
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

added position:absolute; to existing code

Comment: I have this and it works but my image is still zoomed out to much.

Comment: You can add: background-size:contain;

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:absolute;` to the `.container-fluid` class..
Its simple as that..

Note:Adding something to the div makes the background to fit according to the content of the div.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
 .container-fluid{
background-image: url('http://s13.postimg.org/51s3l0x3b/w3schools.png');
background-repeat: repeat-y;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vnwut18f/1/)

Answer (score 0):

It appears your path to the your picture is wrong.

You dont need to set you path as C:....
just

`background-image: url('just ../assets/img.piture.png or ./picture.png or picture.png');`
Depending where your pictures is place in your project. 
ex.

myproject/assets/images/picture.png.. etc.

the example below works.

```css
.container-fluid{
background-image: url('http://www.fillmurray.com/100/100');
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container-fluid"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use in your style may help you

```
.container-fluid
    {
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url('DomPic/photo1.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size:contain;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather was the wrong way Image. Please check again.

```
background-image: url('folder/picture.jpg');
```